# What pipeline is triggered when a form is created in the forms builder

Tags: sitecore-forms, pipelines

I just tried to create a form based on template that was created before. The mail campaign is set up correctly in the template, but the problem is that all token mappings are lost for the new form.

I want to map the tokens for the mail campaign configuration for a form just created via form builder using pipelines. What is the correct pipeline to use for this?

Comment: A form is just an item, so maybe `item:saved` or `item:saving` ?

Comment: Not sure much but I tried to see ShowConfig and found a pipeline named forms.renderForm, you can view this. For more information, you can see Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.config at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceForms

Answer (score 3):

Look at `forms.saveForm` pipeline in the `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Pipelines.Client.config`configuration file; the default settings are

```
<forms.saveForm>
   <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Pipelines.SaveForm.CreateModels, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client" resolve="true" />
   <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Pipelines.SaveForm.GenerateNames, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client">
      <defaultItemName>Form Item</defaultItemName>
   </processor>
   <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Pipelines.SaveForm.CheckAccessRights, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client" resolve="true" />
   <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Pipelines.SaveForm.UpdateItems, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client" resolve="true" />
</forms.saveForm>
```